# AltGr + Space AHK script makes ctrl stuck

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey

When I write in Polish I have to use right Alt (AltGr) to write special symbols. Sometimes when the symbol was at the end of the word I would press space before releasing alt, which would not produce the space key. I've started running a simple script to fix that issue:

```
<^>!Space::Send, {Space}
```

Unfortunately I believe this caused another issue - sometimes my ctrl key gets "stuck" and I start using random Ctrl combinations while writing. How can I improve that script to fix that issue?

I'm not sure what exact combination makes this happen, it's not always and I can't seem to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Among other [debugging methods](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#debug) you can try

- [#HotkeyModifierTimeout](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_HotkeyModifierTimeout.htm) affects the behavior of hotkey modifiers:
  Ctrl, Alt, Win, and Shift.
- Install the keyboard hook by adding the line [#InstallKeybdHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_InstallKeybdHook.htm).
- Use the [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) method.
- Put this code at specific positions in your script (within hotkey
  definitions that send the control key or in a timer) and look in the
  KeyHistory (after closing the message box) in which situations the
  key gets stuck:

```
If GetKeyState("Ctrl")           ; If the OS believes the key to be in (logical state),
{
    If !GetKeyState("Ctrl","P")  ; but the user isn't physically holding it down (physical state)
    {
        Send {Ctrl Up}
        MsgBox,,, Ctrl released
        KeyHistory
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue? Giving feedback and sharing knowledge help other users who are searching for similar solutions.